# Combining query filters with CRM FilterExpression

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to write the following a (pseudo)query in C# for CRM 4:

```
Status = active 
AND 
(
    mail = somemail 
    OR 
    (
        firstName like firstNameSearchTerm 
        AND 
        lastName like LastNameSearchTerm
    )
)
```

The problem is, that middle names might be part of firstName or LastName. I am having a hard time putting this into ConditionExpressions / FilterExpressions.

```
#region mail conditions
            // Create the ConditionExpression.
            ConditionExpression mail1Condition = new ConditionExpression();
            mail1Condition.AttributeName = "emailaddress1";
            mail1Condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
            mail1Condition.Values = new object[] { Registration.Email };

            ConditionExpression mail2Condition = new ConditionExpression();
            mail2Condition.AttributeName = "emailaddress2";
            mail2Condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
            mail2Condition.Values = new object[] { Registration.Email };

            ConditionExpression mail3Condition = new ConditionExpression();
            mail3Condition.AttributeName = "emailaddress3";
            mail3Condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
            mail3Condition.Values = new object[] { Registration.Email };

            ConditionExpression statusCondition = new ConditionExpression();
            statusCondition.AttributeName = "statuscode";
            statusCondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
            statusCondition.Values = new object[] { "1" };

            FilterExpression mailFilter = new FilterExpression();
            mailFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
            mailFilter.Conditions = new ConditionExpression[] { mail1Condition, mail2Condition, mail3Condition };

            #endregion mail conditions

            #region name conditions




            /* FIRST NAME */
            FilterExpression firstNameFilter = new FilterExpression();
            firstNameFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
            List<ConditionExpression> firstNameConditions = new List<ConditionExpression>();

            var firstAndMiddleNames = Registration.FirstName.Trim().Split(' ');
            firstAndMiddleNames = firstAndMiddleNames.Select(s => s.Replace(s, "%"+s+"%")).ToArray(); // Add wildcard search
            foreach (var item in firstAndMiddleNames)
            {
                ConditionExpression firstNameCondition = new ConditionExpression();
                firstNameCondition.AttributeName = "firstname";
                firstNameCondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
                firstNameCondition.Values = new object[] { item };
                firstNameConditions.Add(firstNameCondition);
            }
            firstNameFilter.Conditions = firstNameConditions.ToArray();

            /* LAST NAME */
            FilterExpression lastNameFilter = new FilterExpression();
            lastNameFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
            List<ConditionExpression> lastNameConditions = new List<ConditionExpression>();
            var lastAndMiddleNames = Registration.LastName.Trim().Split(' ');
            lastAndMiddleNames = lastAndMiddleNames.Select(s => s.Replace(s, "%" + s + "%")).ToArray(); // Add wildcard search
            foreach (var item in lastAndMiddleNames)
            {
                ConditionExpression lastNameCondition = new ConditionExpression();
                lastNameCondition.AttributeName = "lastname";
                lastNameCondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
                lastNameCondition.Values = new object[] { item };
                lastNameConditions.Add(lastNameCondition);
            }
            lastNameFilter.Conditions = firstNameConditions.ToArray();



            #endregion name conditions

            FilterExpression nameFilter = new FilterExpression();
            nameFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;                
            nameFilter.Filters = new FilterExpression[] { firstNameFilter, lastNameFilter };


            // Create the outer most filter to AND the state condition with the other filters
            FilterExpression stateFilter = new FilterExpression();
            stateFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
            stateFilter.Conditions = new ConditionExpression[] { statusCondition };
            stateFilter.Filters = new FilterExpression[] { nameFilter };

            query.EntityName = EntityName.contact.ToString();
            query.Criteria = stateFilter;
            query.ColumnSet = columns;
            BusinessEntityCollection contacts = Service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

I
The query currently bypasses the mail filter for debugging purposes.
The result is that it finds all contacts matching the firstname or lastname (should be AND). Why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simple typo in the following line

```
lastNameFilter.Conditions = firstNameConditions.ToArray();
```

should be

```
lastNameFilter.Conditions = lastNameConditions.ToArray();
```